# Swing: JList selection gets stuck on list item

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have found this intermittent behaviour with the JList class. If you select an item in the List in the order in which the they displayed i.e. top to bottom there is no problem. However if you want to select items that do not lie immediately below the one you previously selected the cursor jumps to the one it wants you to select i.e. it gets stuck at an item in the list.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- see Oracle tutorial  [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)
- there are

  a) single selection mode

  b) single interval selection mode

  c) multiple interval selection mode
- rest is described in tutorial [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- probably you search for `multiple interval selection mode`

Comment: I have tried changing the selection mode and unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue.